# Rake and Rails console throwing Postgres exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, ruby-2.1

We have a legacy Rails 4.1 application running on Ubuntu 22.04 TLS (rbenv 1.2.0, ruby 2.1.10, pg gem 4.0.1, Postgres 10) that runs correctly, but Rake (12.3.3) and Rails c (when accessing ActiveRecord objects) consistently dump core with a segmentation fault at .rbenv/versions/2.1.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831.

Rails log shows a successful migration run a few months ago and a few deprecation warnings (active record whitelist_attributes, fixed since then, and others not fixed but unrelated to database operations as far as we can tell).

Can anyone point to a possible cause of such behavioral divergence between Rails and Rake (or rails c when used to access ActiveRecord objects) if they’re both supposedly using the same activerecord gem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Am I reading that right that you're using Rails 4.1 and somehow ActiveRecord 4.0.1? I mean aside from all the other "unsupported software" red flags, that's a fairly big one.

Comment: Also, you said you're using "pg gem 4.0.1" - that doesn't exist. Being accurate in your versions here is going to be critical if you want anything other than "you need to upgrade" responses.

Comment: My mistake. pg gem is at 0.21.0 (also tried with 0.20.0, same results) and Active Record gem is 4.0.1 while Rails is 4.0.1. But the main question is why would Rails work normally and Rake core dump if they're both using the same ActiveRecord gem.

Comment: Well, the answer is that no one has ever tested 10 year old Rails with 6 year old pg on 7 year old ruby hosted on brand new Ubuntu. So you're in unknown waters and if anything works it's by chance.

Comment: OK, thanks. Maybe somebody else has a different perspective?